# Firefox mobile error console missing

Tags: javascript, android, debugging, mobile, browser

I'm working on a mobile website, and it works fine in the Android stock browser. In Firefox some JavaScript functions don't work. So I was googling for the error console. I found a support page wich gives information about the error console of an early version.

Is there an error console in [Firefox for mobile version 14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox_for_mobile#History) (2012-06-26)?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is hidden, but adding [`browser.console.showInPanel`](http://starkravingfinkle.org/blog/2009/06/embedding-the-error-console-in-fennec/) and  [`devtools.errorconsole.enabled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Error_Console) then setting both to 'true' in [`about:config`](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/Fennec/Tips#Hidden_Preferences) will enable the console and preferences panel for JavaScript debugging purposes.

Here is how to find the error console icon:

- [Firefox Mobile: Enabling the Error Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Firefox_Mobile:_Enabling_the_Error_Console)

It seems that the Error Console is deprecated, so bookmarklets are the simplest of the [remaining mobile debugging alternatives](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/08/14/debugging-javascript-on-android-and-ios/):

- Android Console:

```
javascript:(function(){if((/android/gi).test(navigator.appVersion)){console={"_log":[],"log":function(){var%20arr=[];for(var%20i=0;i%20\""+value+"\"");}},"show":function(){alert(this._log.join("\n"));this._log=[];}};window.onerror=function(msg,url,line){console.log("ERROR:%20\""+msg+"\"%20at%20\""+"\",%20line%20"+line);}window.addEventListener("touchstart",function(e){if(e.touches.length===3){console.show();}});}})();
```

- Firebug Lite:

```
javascript:(function(F,i,r,e,b,u,g,L,I,T,E){if(F.getElementById(b))return;E=F[i+'NS']&&F.documentElement.namespaceURI;E=E?F[i+'NS'](E,'script'):F[i]('script');E[r]('id',b);E[r]('src',I+g+T);E[r](b,u);(F[e]('head')[0]||F[e]('body')[0]).appendChild(E);E=new%20Image;E[r]('src',I+L);})(document,'createElement','setAttribute','getElementsByTagName','FirebugLite','4','firebug-lite.js','releases/lite/latest/skin/xp/sprite.png','https://getfirebug.com/','#startOpened');
```

Comment: Ok, I have added this, but I don't see any where to make the console show up, how do I do that?  (using version 25, if that makes any difference which it should not.)

Comment: Restart the browser, then click the bug icon in the preference panel to see JS errors.

Comment: Well first of all there is no "restart" since this is Android and it kills the process whenever it likes.  But even if I exit Firefox and come back, I don't have a preference panel anywhere.  How do I get to it?

Comment: Drag the window so you can see the right-hand toolbar, and press the button at the bottom right to open the preference panel.
Tap the button near the lower left with a "bug" icon. A screen titled "Error Console" will appear.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by drag the window, it's fixed on the screen, the only thing that will drag is any contents on the page.  Have never seen a toolbar on the right side.

Comment: The document link you added says that it is only valid for firefox mobile < 14.  Since @bitstarr asked explicitly about version 14 I assumed your reply was still valid.  It's a shame they removed this feature.

Comment: Sorry, it seems that remote debugging is the only option now.