# Live streaming in video js is not working in Android Firefox

Tags: video-streaming, rtsp, video.js

Live stream in video js is not working in Android Firefox browser.

Below is my code:

```
<source src="rtsp://****" type="rtsp/mp4"/>
<source src="http://****" type='application/x-mpegur'>
```

Comment: Have you checked your JS console? Have you checked this browser supports this stream type?

Comment: how can i view js console in mobile firefox ? please help and yes video js supports android also.

Comment: A quick search [found this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11688340/firefox-mobile-error-console-missing).

Comment: You should take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097042/does-rtsp-support-streaming-file-video-mp4.

Comment: Hi @Funti did you resolve your issue? We are also try to implement an rtsp/mp4 stream with video html5 (videojs) or anything like this.